Why is $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{∂D}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-\omega_0}dz$ either $0$ or $1$ if $f$ satisfies certain requirements, including injectivity?
I've come across this problem:
Assume that $f$ is holomorphic and injective on the closed disk $\overline D = [z : |z| ≤ ρ]$, and that $f(z) \neq \omega_0$ for each $z$ on the boundary $∂D = [z : |z| = ρ]$. Show that the integral below is either $0$ or $1$.
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{∂D}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-\omega_0}dz$$
In an attempt to solve it, I've introduced the function $g(z)=f(z)-\omega_0$, which is holomorphic and injective on $\overline D$, and non-zero on ${∂D}$.
From the argument principle, it seems to follow that $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{∂D}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-\omega_0}dz$ =
$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{∂D}\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}dz$ = the number of zeros of $g$ in $D$, counting multiplicity. (Since $g$ is holomorphic in $D$ it doesn't have any singularities there.)
Now due to the injective property, we can safely say that the number of zeros of $g$ in $D$, in an absolute sense, is either zero or one, but it's unclear if we have any reason to believe anything about the multiplicity of the zero, provided it exists.
If I’m not mistaken, a holomorphic function is locally invertible (which is probably the same as locally injective) if the derivative is non-zero at a point, but is there a way to reason the other way around and go from injectivity to something regarding the derivative? That's the question. Non-zero derivative everywhere would imply that all zeros are simple, I think, which is the conclusion that we want to be able to draw.

Yes, an injective holomorphic function has an everywhere non-zero derivative. For a proof see this.

I must admit, it looks just like Cauchy's integral formula of the function 1, but with the variable $f(z)$ instead of $z$.

@Julio Puerta Okay, good. Is that an elementary and well known result? Can it found in introductory complex analysis textbooks such as the one by Saff and Snider?

Yes, it is a very well known result. It should be in every introductory complex analysis book.

@Julio Puerta I see. But maybe this result is counterintuitive considering that it doesn't seem to hold in the real analysis case. Isn't the function $f(x)=x^3$ injective although its derivative is zero at the origin?

Yes, it does not hold in the real case. This happens a lot in complex analysis, we do not get 'weird' counterexamples there, everything just works.
